# Login user's Name not displayed

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have developed an ASP.NET web application. The login page and logout functionality is working correctly. I have added a new method to display the logged in user's name. After adding this method I can't login to my application. I don't think i've added this method correctly. 
[image: Login]
Can you please help?

**Login.aspx**

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  try 
  {
    DataTable dtUser = UserRegistration.GetUserByUserName(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
    if (dtUser.Rows.Count > 0) 
    {
      lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Login Successful!";

      oLoginData = txtUserName.Text;

      Session["intUserId"] = dtUser.Rows[0]["intUserId"].ToString();
      Session["DisplayName"] = dtUser.Rows[0]["DisplayName"].ToString();
      Response.Redirect("~/WebForms/Home/Home.aspx");

    } 
    else 
    {
      lblErrorMessage.Text = "Incorrect User Name or Password";
      txtUserName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LavenderBlush;
      txtPassword.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LavenderBlush;
      return;
    }
  } 
  catch 
  {
    lblErrorMessage.Text = "Incorrect User Name or Password";
    txtUserName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LavenderBlush;
    txtPassword.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LavenderBlush;
    return;
  }
}
}
```

---

**Site.Masters.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  if ((Session["intUserId"] == null)) 
  {
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
  } 
  else 
  {
    //lblLocation.Text = Session["LocationName"].ToString();
    lblUser.Text = "Logged User :" + Session["DisplayName"].ToString();
  }
}
```

**GetUserByUserName**

```
 public static DataTable GetUserByUserName(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            DataTable dsResult = new DataTable();
            try
            {


                String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TCDMSConnection"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

                con.Open();
                com.Connection = con;
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.CommandText = "spUserValidation";

                SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[2];

                sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@Username", UserName);
                sqlParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@Password", Password);

                if (sqlParam != null)
                {
                    com.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParam);
                }

                da.SelectCommand = com;
                da.Fill(dsResult);

                con.Close();

                return dsResult;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }




        }


    }
```

[image]

Comment: What happened in site master page load when session is null? are you getting display name? and you write cant login, please explain and what error you get while debugging.

Comment: i cant login my application, no any errors, login page displayed login success message, but not login

Comment: i want to make user login , after current user name displayed

Comment: are you debug in site.master "if ((Session["intUserId"] == null))" line, so after login process done and redirect process of home page , it again come to above line as I assume you are given the master page include in home page. check and see where it goes while home page load in above line of master page.

Comment: @Ajay2707 , Sir, What i do ? can you code it or give me a some example, i can do it

Comment: Session["intUserId"] must be null. Check if in your database that field has value. Also you set lblSuccessMessage.Text to Successful before setting session variables so in case of an error you never set it back to empty string.

Comment: Do you see master page or user remains on login page ?

Comment: Removed previous comment, converted it to answer with sample for how to fix..

Comment: @PhantomAssassin please show code of `GetUserByUserName`

Comment: @PhantomAssassin change your error message within catch { } statement to a proper one. I think you have some database related exception that happens in GetUserByUserName()

Comment: @PhantomAssassin consider catching and logging your error to your error logging system. If you don't have one, Consider using Elmah - easy and simple to setup https://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: @PhantomAssassin please show code of `GetUserByUserName` method.

Comment: @MairajAhmad Sir Im updated my question

Comment: @PhantomAssassin have you debugged your code that if you are not getting any exception.

Comment: yes sir im debug  no any  exception

Comment: im already used it my another project its working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution,
im not add correctly SP for **DisplayName** `Col`

```
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        UserId,
        UserName,
        FullName,
        UserCatagoryId,
         DisplayName

    FROM UserRegistrations
    WHERE UserName = @Username AND Password = @Password


END
```

Answer (score 4):

If your login page `Login.aspx` is using the same master page `Site.Master` then you seem to have a redirect loop.

When you go to the application, you get redirected to `Login.aspx` since you are not yet logged on. When `Login.aspx` is loading, this part:

```
if ((Session["intUserId"] == null))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```

of the master page will execute and cause a redirect back to `Login.aspx`, which will cause the whole thing to repeat.

The browser will notice that the request is getting redirected *many* times and will eventually give up and show some kind of *Page cannot be displayed* error.

To fix it you need to avoid redirecting if the currently running page is already `Login.aspx`. For instance like this (in **Site.Master.cs**):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath.ToLower().EndsWith("login.aspx"))
    {
        if ((Session["intUserId"] == null))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblUser.Text = "Logged User :" + Session["DisplayName"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir thanks for the help , Im try to this but not work (Incorrect User Name or Password Login Successful!) displayed login page

Comment: Are you getting a Login Successful message? or a Incorrect User... message? or both?

Comment: i getting both message

Comment: @PhantomAssassin Hi, edited the answer a bit, try again now. Previous version was doing the `lblUser.Text = "Logged User :" + Session["DisplayName"].ToString();` part even in `Login.aspx` which of course caused an `Exception` if the `DisplayName` was missing in the Session...

Comment: Sir Im try to do that, But im try to login i cant login (Look at image)

Answer (score 2):

As per your comments you are not getting any `exception` and code is working fine. So there are few things you can try.

- Don't use `Response.Redirect("yourpage")` instead use `Response.Redirect("yourpage",false)`;
- Use `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` method to redirect
  from    login page insetead of `Response.Redirect()`.
- Also check your web.config file and make sure you have a valid
  value for `timeout` property of session and `cookiesless` session is
  enabled.

  ```
  <sessionState
     mode="InProc"
     cookieless="false"
     timeout="100"/>
  ```

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_) is an article explaining first two points.

Answer (score 1):

`[assuming your GetUserByUserName method works fine]` Try to change you Page_load method to

```
   if ( Session["intUserId"] != null)
        {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["DisplayName"].ToString()))
            {
                 // Your Display name is having blank space , null value
            }
           else
           {
               //lblLocation.Text = Session["LocationName"].ToString();
               lblUser.Text = "Logged User :" + Session["DisplayName"].ToString(); 
           }

        }
        else
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: Sir Im try to do that, but cant login

Comment: you can't login or you are unable to show username?

Comment: Sir, what i make it

Comment: Im remove the   This, after  ican login but  not a displayed current user`Session["DisplayName"] = dtUser.Rows[0]["DisplayName"].ToString();`

Comment: @PhantomAssassin can you post(show) the data within your dtUser, here?

Answer (score -1):

Hope your login code works fine then simply use

```
Session["DisplayName"] = txtUserName.Text;
```

instead of

```
Session["DisplayName"] = dtUser.Rows[0]["DisplayName"].ToString();
```